# Why can't Eureka access the app that has successfully registered in spring microservice

Tags: spring, microservices, ribbon, netflix-eureka

This problem occurred in a specific environment: Eureka successfully registered the app (I call it A). In the vm where Eureka is located, the status of A can be accessed (the status is up). However, accessing A in spring microservice shows that target application is not online.

**Sincerely ask for your help
**

Known conditions are as follows：

1.This set of microservices works normally in other environments.

2.Visit ~/eureka/apps to see Service A successfully.

3.Visit A's ~/health on the machine where Eureka is located, and the result is UP.

4.However, the result of calling org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient#choose(java.lang.String) is null.Therefore, the error "target application is not online." will be reported (We set it ourselves).

`instance = loadBalancer.choose(applicationName);`

5.If we restart eureka, the microservice can temporarily access A, but the above error will occur soon.

**Dependent version is

spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.2.8.RELEASE.jar**

Comment: Could you solve this issue? I have faced same issue(